# emailing a larger set (15-20) of photos

Tags: photos

If I need to send a set of 15 photo images via email, what is the best way to do this? Will I need to send them in multiple emails? I understand that I should resize the files to 72 dpi.

Comment: DPI has absolutely no relevance to images on a computer. All they have are dimensions in pixels. DPI only comes into play if you want to print them.

Comment: what are you sending from iOS or macOS? Mail.app or another app?

Answer (score 2):

For sharing photos, you can use iCloud Photo sharing. For more information, refer to the Apple support document, [iCloud Photo Sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202786).

If the recipient are not using Apple devices, they can still access the photos via iCloud website.

Answer (score 2):

> If I need to send a set of 15 photo images via email, what is the best
> way to do this?

It sounds like this isn't something for "social media" where uploading to Facebook, Flickr, or another image sharing site would work.

#### Cloud File Sharing

The best way, at this point in time (IMO) is to use a cloud (file sharing service) service like OneDrive, Box, or DropBox.  Personally, I use [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/auth/); Apple (internal) uses [Box](https://www.box.com/).

The benefit here is that you can create folder and share a link (read only or with editing privileges) and share that amongst the people you need to give access to.  With direct integration into Finder, you can share access to a folder without going to a website.  The link you generate can then be safely emailed to your recipients.

[image: OneDrive Share Link]

The "beauty" of OneDrive (and similar File Sync sites) is that it's cross platform; meaning it works on macOS, iOS, Android, Windows and even BSD/Linux (no shell integration, but web access works great).

#### Sending via Email

> If I need to send a set of 15 photo images via email, what is the best
> way to do this?

Email might be a viable option, but you could hit limitations imposed by your email provider and/or ISP limiting the total size/number of attachments.  The email clients (Mail.app, Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.) don't care how many or how big they are - it's the servers that do.

The "best" way is definitely to zip the files to compress them and limit the attachment to just 1 file.  However, that doesn't eliminate the fact that the single zip file might be more than allowable size.  In this case, you would have to break it up into smaller ZIPs to come under the imposed limits.